# OpenGL multiple Sampler2D (array) examples?

Tags: opengl, graphics, shader

I find it surprisingly frustrating that it is so difficult to find examples of sampler2d arrays such as

```
uniform sampler2D myTextureSampler[5];
```

How would one store the uniform location of this?:

```
gl.GetUniformLocation(program, "myTextureSampler")
```

Would one simply use:

```
gl.GetUniformLocation(program, "myTextureSampler[0]")
gl.GetUniformLocation(program2, "myTextureSampler[2]")
```

How would one go about using multiple textures like this:

```
gl.BindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 1)
gl.BindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 2)
```

etc..

```
gl.ActiveTexture(gl.TEXTURE0)
gl.ActiveTexture(gl.TEXTURE1)
```

etc..

Note: this code is not pure c++ opengl. Just looking for the basic concept on how it would be done.

A simple example of passing, getting uniform location for a sampler2d array would be great. Does anyone have experience with this stuff?

Comment: What's wrong with the obvious answers? The way [arrays of uniforms work](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)#Uniform_management) from the GL side doesn't change just because you're using an opaque type like `sampler2D`.

Comment: The above are not answers. They are merely speculations of the way I think it would work.  Currently, I have not had much success getting it to work. Seems like a pretty straightforward way of getting easy stack overflow points and help out a lot of people :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume it's the same as all other shader array accesses and that:

```c
glGetUniformLocation(program, "myTextureSampler[0]");
```

will work.

To use multiple textures you should set the slot which you want to put your texture in to active first:

```c
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
```

and then you can bind your texture:

```c
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.handle);
```

The second parameter is the handle you got from `glGenTextures()`.

Then you match the `sampler2D` with the appropriate texture by calling:

```c
glUniform1i(location, 0);
```

The first parameter is the location you got back from calling `glGetUniformLocation()`.
The second parameter is the active texture slot (`GL_TEXTURE0` in this case).

Comment: So the weird thing is when I try this and then i access myTextureSampler[1] in my fragment shader, everything works.. Should index 1 throw an error since I set the uniform location to index 0?  I have yet to try it on two actual textures. Maybe when you assign myTextureSampler[0] and myTextureSampler[1] then it automatically fills them both in as separate units?

Comment: @efel That's because the default value of the uniform is already `0`, so it refers to the texture bound to `GL_TEXTURE0` by default.

Answer (score 3):

The current answer has been here for a long time, but is not correct.

What you are using is uniform arrays.

For a shader declaration like:

```c-like
uniform sampler2D myTextureSampler[5];
```

...you get the uniform location of the array, without specifying a subscript:

```cpp
glGetUniformLocation(my_uniform, "myTextureSampler");
```

...then set its values in a single operation from an array:

```cpp
GLfloat values[5] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f};
glUniform1fv(my_uniform, 5, values);
```

Documentation: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml